# HABTM error not unique table alias

Tags: cakephp

I am trying to link a HABTM model with joins but I keep getting this error . There is a unique table with Tutor so I am not sure why i get this error?
Here is the controller and model with the relationship

Error: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1066 Not unique table/alias: 'Tutor'

```
class Subject extends AppModel {
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(

    'Tutor' => array(
        'className' => 'Tutor',
        'joinTable' => 'tutors_subjects',
        'foreignKey' => 'subject_id',
        'associationForeignKey' => 'tutor_id',
        'unique' => 'keepExisting',
        'conditions' => '',

    )
);
```

}

```
class Tutor extends AppModel {
    ..

    public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array(
        'Subject' => array(
            'className' => 'Subject',
            'joinTable' => 'tutors_subjects',
            'foreignKey' => 'tutor_id',
            'associationForeignKey' => 'subject_id',
            'unique' => 'keepExisting',
            'conditions' => '',

        ),

    );

class TutorsController extends AppController {

 public function tutordetails() {

     //    $tutor=$this->Tutor->find('all', array(  'conditions'=>array('Tutor.id'=> 1),'recursive' => -1 ) );
     //    $this->set( 'tutor',$tutor);
       //   debug($tutor);



            $options2['joins'] = array(
               array('table' => 'tutors_subjects',
                'alias' => 'TutorsSubject',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'Tutor.id = TutorsSubject.id',
                 )
                 ),

                array('table' => 'subjects',
                'alias' => 'Subject',
                'type' => 'LEFT',
                'conditions' => array(
                'TutorsSubject.subject_id=Subject.id',
                 )
                 ),

                 array( 'table' => 'tutors',
            'alias' => 'Tutor',
            'type' => 'LEFT',
            'conditions' => array(
            'TutorsSubject.tutor_id = Tutor.id',
        )

            ));





            $options2['fields'] = array('Subject.*','TutorsSubject.*','Tutor.*');



            $options2['conditions'] = array('Tutor.id'  => 2);
            $subject=$this->Tutor->find('first',$options2);


            $this->set('subject', $subject);
            debug($subject);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is this code within your JOIN clause:

```
 array( 'table' => 'tutors',
        'alias' => 'Tutor',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
        'TutorsSubject.tutor_id = Tutor.id',
```

You are performing a find on the Tutors model trying to self JOIN and using the same alias.

Try this:

```
 array( 'table' => 'tutors',
        'alias' => 'TutorOther',
        'type' => 'LEFT',
        'conditions' => array(
        'TutorsSubject.tutor_id = TutorOther.id',
```

Comment: HELP!I just found out the join doesnt work. I dont get an error but I dont get any associated records . I just get NULL from other tables tutor.id=2 which is not true.  $this->Tutor->recursive = -1;
            $options2['conditions'] = array('Tutor.id'  => 2);

Comment: @ajt - Do you have SQL code that works already that you need to put into Cakephp syntax? If so, edit the original question and add that working sql

Comment: what I might do is start another question as my original question has been answered as this is getting a bit confusing by adding a 2nd question